# How is a hash with consecutive numbered keys different from an array?

Tags: ruby

Consider:

```
foo = {
    0 =>    "a",
    1 =>    "b",
    2 =>    "c"
}

bar = ["a","b","c"]
```

Functionally, these seem to be the same to me. Is the difference just that they're different data types, even though the data itself is effectively the same?

I feel like an array should be a subclass of a hash, the difference being the keys are implied and therefore don't need to be explicitly set by the programmer.

Comment: It's not PHP, you know :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev How'd you know that's my background? :)

Comment: It's the only language I can name off the top of my head that conflates array and dictionary concepts. These are very different. PHP is a weird language.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Lua does it with tables, but oddly enough dict and list behaviors are different within the same datatype. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev awk also comes to mind…

Comment: @SergioTulentsev http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2015/01/12/the-right-tool-for-the-right-job/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are differences both in semantics and implementation.

Semantically, an array is a list of ordered values. Removing an item from the list shifts all the other items in the list. There are a head and tail to the list, and you can insert into it at specific positions. There can be gaps in the list (where there is no value stored at a given index).

Hashes, by contrast, don't necessarily have any defined ordering (though they do in Ruby 1.9+), don't have a head or tail, can't have gaps in iteration, and don't permit insertion in the middle of the iterable order (at least, without resorting the whole hash).

Implementation-wise, they are night and day. Arrays are significantly simpler data structures - under the hood, they're simply a contiguous block of memory which is indexed by (index * struct size). Get/set are both O(1). Hashes, on the other hand, tend to be a list of linked lists. You pass a key through a hash function to determine which linked list in your set the value is to be stored on or retrieved from, and then you iterate the linked list to retrieve the value. Insertion is O(1), retrieval is O(n log n).

While a PHP background might make it seem that Arrays should be a subclass of Hash because of how PHP conflates them, they are very different data structures with different purposes and behaviors, and really should remain separate.

Answer (score 2):

Your assimilation does not extend to some naturally defined concepts.

For example, addition `+` is naturally defined on an array:

```
["a", "b", "c"] + ["d", "e", "f"]
# => ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

If you follow your assimilation and do a similar thing with the hash counterpart `merge`, you get a different result:

```
{0 => "a", 1 => "b", 2 => "c"}.merge({0 => "d", 1 => "e", 2 => "f"}
# => {0 => "d", 1 => "e", 2 => "f"}
```

**Edit** I think what underlies this difference is that consecutive numbering of indices starting at 0 is automatic for an array. Whatever you do to an array, the condition is always satisfied. In order to maintain your assimilation, you have to add a mechanism to "the array part of the hash" to do this.

Comment: While this is true, it doesn't speak to the heart of the OP's question. You can implement a different method other than `#+` or `#merge` that could get you closer to the results (albeit somewhat presumptively). The main issue though is that they "are" different data types. Performance in addition to what @sawa has described are some examples that illustrate the difference.

Answer (score -3):

An array will be more efficient in parsing the data since the MRI (Matz's Ruby Interpreter -- the ruby interpreter) has to evaluate the keys in a hash as strings/symbols rather than integer index values.